# Self-Executing JS Function

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am doing the Codecademy JS training as a review for a course I'm taking soon. I hit the creditCheck function exercise which basically just wants a function that evaluates an integer and returns one value for above 100, and one for below. I thought that the code below should work, but it is running without being called. Why is this happening?

```
creditCheck = function(income)
{
    income *= 1; // one way to convert the variable income into a number.
    if (income>100)
        {
            console.log("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.");
            return true; // this is an actual return value, console.log() always returns "undefined"
        }
    else
        {
            console.log("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.");
            return false;
        }
};
console.log("If the log is executing in the function def then this should print second. Otherwise it's probably being executed by the coding script itself.\n\n")
```

RESOLUTION (Maybe):
So I just tested the script in a console off of the Codecademy site. It doesn't self execute anywhere except on that site. This leads me to believe that there is something funky going on with that page.

More Resolution (also Maybe):
I also added that last line above to test when the function was being called. Since it's the last line in the program, my assumption is that if the execution is in the function body itself, that that last line would print last. This leads me to believe that the grading script is calling the function on its own accord which means that when I add in the actual function calls, it's messing it up.

Comment: `return` isn’t a function, by the way; avoid putting parentheses around it, it’s confusing.

Comment: Nothing in the code you have provided will cause the problem you are describing.

Comment: Sorry, the whole thing looked a lot neater before I futzed with it for a while trying to get it to work right. I still have some of the excel mentality of "if it doesn't work, try adding more parens".

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask; what's with this weird indentation? I've never heard of anyone formatting code that way before...

Comment: I learned Python first, I like indents, and since this is just for familiarizing myself with JS I'm just writing it in whatever way makes it easier for me to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual solution had to do with me calling my own function in the submitted code and the way that the grading function interpreted this. Additionally, the script was expecting some other arrangement of console.log(#whatever) so that was complicating it when I didn't call my own function.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the function you have defined.

```
 var creditCheck = function(income)
    {
        if (income>100)
            {
                return(console.log("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."));
            }
        else
            {
                return(console.log("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that."));
            }

    }; creditCheck(111);
```

Comment: It's specifically that it is running **without** being called that is the issue. For some reason just declaring the function is causing it to run.

Comment: I assume it was you that -1 voted my post.. please undo that childisch stuff, that wont make your post better or help the OP at all... thank you

Comment: :) @Zim84 honestly, I didn't even notice your answer. I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer.

Comment: I believe you, but who the heck has in interesent in my post to be downvoted without leaving a reason why? I don't get it..

Comment: if that's the worst thing to happen to you today, consider yourself lucky; i mean who cares about random jerks on stack? if it happens a lot, review your answer format. even a clear channel has some degree of noise...

Comment: its not the worst, but if you avoid adressing minor stuff you won't end up much better.. and it disturbs me if I try to help/share my knowledge and I got a punch in my face without any explanation.

Comment: To be fair you did answer the wrong question. Your answer is useful for "Why isn't this doing anything?" but not for "Why is this doing something apparently of its own accord?"

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function to have it called ;)

```
creditCheck = function(income)
{
    income *= 1; // one way to convert the variable income into a number.
    if (income>100)
        {
            console.log("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.");
            return true; // this is an actual return value, console.log() always returns "undefined"
        }
    else
        {
            console.log("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.");
            return false;
        }
};
var check = creditCheck(123); // runs the function
alert(check); // and alerts() the result
```

Comment: if the one that wants his post to be the best one and therefore be voted on top may want to undo his negative vote or at least leave a comment WHY my post sucks, that would be very nice...

Comment: Hey dude. I didn't downvote, but the issue isn't that I'm not calling it and it's not running. I am not calling it but it runs anyways, which is screwing up a) the intended operation, b) the damned grading script.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answerers have pointed out, the syntax in the declaration of the function itself is a little, off, and you need to call the function.  Below is code that should correct both problems.  Just copy this code to a new .html file, and open in a browser:

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <h1>Credit Check Example</h1>
 <script>
 function creditcheck(income)
 {
  if (income>100)
    {
        alert("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.");
    }
  else
    {
        alert("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.");
    }

 }

 creditcheck(1000);
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No one Is voted correct yet so I think i'll sort this.

The problem is you need to re-read the question. if is greater than or equal too 100. So the sign is '<=', NOT '<'.

```
creditCheck = function(income){
    if(income>=100){
        return "You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.";
    } else{
        return "Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.";
    }
};


creditCheck(75);
creditCheck(125);
creditCheck(100);
```

Comment: ">=" NOT ">" even. ^_^